# Is nested html tag effect SEO of my page?

Tags: html, seo, googlebot

If I use nested `<html>` in my document like:

```
<html>
<body>
some text
<html>
<body>
some text
</body>
</html>

</body>
<html>
```

Is this put any effect on SEO of my page? Will googlebot crawl and index it or ignore it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nobody here knows how Google is or isn't going to crawl your site today, tomorrow or next week.

Comment: How about you simply produce ***valid HTML*** instead of random tag soup?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is off-topic here and belongs on webmasters.stackexchange

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons described in the description of the [tag:seo] tag

Answer (score 2):

As @Nadeem rightly said, your HTML is not a valid HTML so it would affect the SEO of your page. You can learn more about valid HTML at https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Here's a good read on webmasters.stackexchange [Does excessive markup affect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57628/does-excessive-markup-affect-seo) and this: [Are deep nested HTML tags bad for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98495/are-deep-nested-html-tags-bad-for-seo)

Answer (score 0):

For sure it will affect you SEO since its not a valid HTML and the structure of your page is totally wrong.

First you need to remove the unnecessary tags and start with a valid HTML.